# Use sample() function to apply in a range of column

Tags: r, simulation, apply, sample, sapply

I have a data.frame called "prob" with 3 columns of probabilities.

```
              A              B         C

1         0.346          0.629     0.026

2         0.377          0.529     0.094

3         0.454          0.495     0.051

4         0.338          0.604     0.058

5         0.616          0.331     0.054
```

I want to sample one item from (A,B,C) in each row. So I apply the following function:

```
sapply(prob[,2:5], 
       function(p) sample(x = c(0:2), size = 1, prob = p))
```

R returns an error:

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :    incorrect
>   number of probabilities

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: try `apply(prob[,2:5],1,function(p) sample(x = c(0:2), size = 1, prob = p))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(0.346, 0.377, 0.454, 0.338, 0.616), B = c(0.629, 0.529, 0.495, 0.604, 0.331), C = c(0.026, 0.094, 0.051, 0.058, 0.054)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
apply(df, 1, function(x) sample(names(df), 1, prob = x))
```

output

```
 1   2   3   4   5 
"B" "C" "A" "A" "B"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain why sapply doesn't work?

Comment: sapply is also working when you transform the data like `sapply(as.data.frame(t(prob)),function(p) sample(x = c(0:2), size = 1, prob = p))`. Check the output of `as.list(prob)`, thus the data is included columnwise.

Comment: @Viveme679 `sapply(X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)` ,When X is a data.frame, `sapply` run `FUN` on each column of X.